# Displaying all the results with selector gadget & nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using selector gadget for the first time and am having trouble, when I run the code below, why do I only get the first result to display in the Terminal?

Also, is there any easier way to get the text after the ICD-10 code in the example page, because as of now selector gadget only gets the links, and not the plain text?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10_Chapter_XVII:_Congenital_malformations,_deformations_and_chromosomal_abnormalities"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("li li:nth-child(1) li a , li li ul:nth-child(5) :nth-child(1), .new, li:nth-child(3) li a, li li li:nth-child(10) li:nth-child(9) li:nth-child(4) :nth-child(1) li:nth-child(5) :nth-child(1) :nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) :nth-child(1), li a:nth-child(4), li li li:nth-child(1), #mw-content-text li a:nth-child(5), li :nth-child(4) ul:nth-child(4) :nth-child(1), #mw-content-text li a:nth-child(3)").text
```

Comment: So what do you want as output? Each code (e.g. Q04.1) followed by its description (Arhinencephaly)?

Comment: If you want the first result, use 'at'. If you want all results, use 'search'.

Comment: Output should be all the text After the code in the same line, not the code itself.

Comment: How about the subitems that don't have their own codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets all the text following a bullet with a Q code:

```
puts doc.search('//li[contains(a[@class="external text"]/@href, "icd10")]').map(&:text)
```

The XPath matches a list item (`li`) which contains an external link with `icd10` in the URL, then extracts the text from it.

It's a bit of a broad brushstroke: it gets *all* the text, which means further manipulation will be necessary if you don't want the code, or subitems that don't have a code. But in any case it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css

> Search this node for the first occurrence of CSS rules. Equivalent to css(rules).first See Node#css for more information.

So, if you want to view all of the texts, might I suggest you do this:

```
selectors = ["li li:nth-child(1) li a", "li li ul:nth-child(5) :nth-child(1)", ".new", "li:nth-child(3) li a", "li li li:nth-child(10) li:nth-child(9) li:nth-child(4) :nth-child(1) li:nth-child(5) :nth-child(1) :nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) :nth-child(1)", "li a:nth-child(4)", "li li li:nth-child(1)", "#mw-content-text li a:nth-child(5)", "li :nth-child(4) ul:nth-child(4) :nth-child(1)", "#mw-content-text li a:nth-child(3)"]
selectors.each do |s|
  puts doc.at_css(s).text
end
```